# Is it possible to use Groovy to override a method in a Java class, when that Java class is not instantiated in my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application and I recently started to use Groovy in it. So 99% of my code is still Java.

I read that it is possible to use Groovy to override and add methods to Java classes and I was able to test this by adding a method to the java.lang.String.

But this only works when I use the string in a Groovy class. The overridden method is not considered as being overridden in a Java class.

Here's some code:

```
/*
 * This is a Java class
 */
public class CTabItem {
   ...
   private API
   ...
   public void setControl(Control control){
       private API
   }
}

/*
 * This is also a Java class
 */
public class Control {
   ...
   private API
   ...
}

/*
 * This is also a Java class
 */
public class OtherClass {
  ...
  private API
  ...
  private void someMethodIDontKnow(){
     Control control = new Control();
     CTabItem tab = new CTabItem();
     tab.setControl(control);
  }
}

/*
 * This is a Groovy class
 */
public class MyViewPart extends org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart {
     ....
     public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
          /* parent (or the parent of parent) is a Control
           which is set somewhere in a CTabItem to which
           I don't get access  */
     }        
}
```

I need to get the tab from the control. But since it's not me who instantiates MyViewPart, but some private API, I have no access to it.
Is there something Groovy could do for me here? Any suggestion or code is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: How would you solve it in Java? Using reflection?

Comment: I don't know, I was hoping to solve it in Groovy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is: no, it's not possible if the code creating the object and calling the method is pure Java (i.e., non-Groovy) code. Groovy does its magic by intercepting all method calls on objects (both Java objects and Groovy objects) and using its [ExpandoMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) to add the behavior. However, it can't change how pure Java code determines which method to call on a pure Java class. To see, run the following sample code:

```
// UseTheString.java (a pure Java class)
public class UseTheString {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String s = "Hello world";
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s.substring(1));
        ModifyStringClass.messWithMetaClasses(s);
        System.out.println(s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

and

```
// ModifyStringClass.groovy (a Groovy class)
class ModifyStringClass {
    public static messWithMetaClasses(String t) {
        java.lang.String.metaClass.substring = { int n -> "!" }
        println(t.substring(1))
    }
}
```

You'll get the output:

```
Hello world
ello world
!
ello world
```

As you can see, Groovy can override the method on a pure Java object if it is called from other Groovy code, but it can't change how the Java code uses it.