# spock - mock static method is not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am trying to mock the one of static method `readAttributes` using groovy's `metaClass` convention, but the real method get invoked.

This is how I mocked the static function:

```
def "test"() {
    File file = fold.newFile('file.txt')
    Files.metaClass.static.readAttributes = { path, cls ->
        null
    }

    when:
        fileUtil.fileCreationTime(file)
    then:
        1 * fileUtil.LOG.debug('null attribute')
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

My java method

```
public Object fileCreationTime(File file) {
    try {
        BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
        if(attributes == null) {
            LOG.debug("null attribute");
        }  
        //doSomething
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        //doSomething
    }
    return new Object();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved the issue using one level of indirection. I created an instance method of the `test class` which acts like a wrapper for this static call.

```
public BasicFileAttributes readAttrs(File file) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
}
```

and from the test I mocked the instance method.

```
FileUtil util = Spy(FileUtil);
util.readAttrs(file) >> { null }
```

which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that it's not possible, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884190/is-it-possible-to-use-groovy-to-override-a-method-in-a-java-class-when-that-jav) question.

It would be possible if either:

- code under test was written in groovy
- *mocked* (altered) class must be instantiated in groovy code.

The workaround is to extract the logic returning the attributes to another class which will be mocked instead of use `Files` directly.

Comment: @Suganthan have you copied the example I provided as is? Cloaure's args are also very important.

Comment: Yes, I did the same, the intermediate assertion workd with no issue, but still the method get invoked

Comment: @Suganthan could you please then provide na runnable example? Without it, it might difficult to help.

Comment: @Suganthan, if you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Comment: I thought it is due to final class(Files) and it is private method is a root cause

Comment: @Suganthan, final classes can be mocked as well, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121999/mock-final-class-in-spock/34150867#34150867)

Comment: Sorry it is not private method `private constructor`. `Private Constructor` might be a cause. Files having private constructor, but not the `String class`

Comment: @Suganthan, may be. However in groovy `private` is not `private` at all ;)

Comment: Yes, that make sense, sure I ll to find out the root cause and update my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use GroovySpy for this, as stated in [spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_mocking_static_methods)

In your case, it would be:

```
def filesClass = GroovySpy(Files, global: true)
filesClass.readAttributes(*_) >> null
```

Comment: This does not work when mocking static (Java) class within the object of test. In other words, the one instantiated not from Groovy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824315/mock-static-method-with-groovymock-or-similar-in-spock